# What happens if an answer is accepted twice?

Tags: support

What happens if an answer is accepted twice?

Is it possible? What happens with the reputation on the user who answer and in the user who ask?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You mean as in they deselect your answer and re-select your answer later?

It would take away the 15 reputation (accepted answer reputation) when the answer was deselected. The 15 rep would return when your answer was selected a second time. So you would only gain 15 rep like you should.

Comment: Ooops I think I took 10 pts from you by playing with the upvote control. Would you re-edit it I would re-upvote :)

Comment: Sure, as long as this answered your question.